# Antiderivative of an odd function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> Is the antiderivative of an odd function even?

The answer given by the book is yes.
However, I found a counterexample defined in $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\ln |x|+1& x<0\\\ln |x|&x>0\end{cases}$$
Its derivative is $\frac 1x$, which is an odd function.

> Question: is my counterexample right?

Comment: I think the question implies that the odd function in question must contain $0$ in its domain. Otherwise, you can't integrate it across a symmetric interval

Comment: You can actually do this for any odd function if you allow a piecewise function definition, as there are infinitely many anti-derivatives for a given function --- simply pick two that differ by a constant, then piece them together.  E.g. consider $F(x) = x^4 + [x>0]$, where $[\cdot]$ is the Iverson bracket (equal to $1$ when the condition is true, otherwise $0$), which is an antiderivative of $f(x) = x^3$.

Comment: @apnorton I don't think so. Your $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, it contradicts with the definition of antiderivative.

Comment: A much simpler example (and a continuous function) is $f(x) = x$. Its antiderivative is $x^2 + C$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. The antiderivative will be even if and only if $C = 0$, so in general the antiderivative of an odd function is not even.

Comment: $x^2 + C$ is even for any $C$.  For the opposite case of whether the antiderivative of an even function is odd, this point would be valid.

Comment: @1123581321 Constants are even.

Comment: @KemonoChen Define my function over $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ just like yours. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that $f$ should be defined on an interval $I$ which contains $0$ and is symmetric to $0$. If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ on $I$, then there is a constant $c$ such that

$$F(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt+c.$$

If you now calculate $F(-x)$ with the substitution $s=-t$ you will get $F(-x)=F(x).$

Try it !

Comment: I only get that when c is zero...

Comment: @lalala If $f(t)=\sin(t)$ then $\int_0^x f(t) \,dt = 1-\cos(t)$.  Choose a $c$ such as $-1$ or if you prefer $1$ and do as Fred suggests to find $F(-x)$. What do you get?